# Google Analytics v4 campaign in android

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

I am implementing Google Analytics v4 Campaign Measurement in Android.

In the beginning, let me show you iOS' document,

```
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns
```

> 3. Confirm that the IDFA is being sent
>
> Google Analytics requires Identifier for Advertiser (IDFA) for iOS
>   campaign tracking. Ensure that you are using Google Analytics SDK for
>   iOS version 3.10 or higher, you have enabled IDFA collection, and are
>   tracking one or more screen views or events in your app.

It explicitly explains I should use screen views or events, and I understood Campaigns are transmitted with these information.

In case of Android's document, it does not have such contents.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

If I use CampaignTrackingRecevier and CampaignTrackingService, document says I don't need additional transmission.

However, I made experiences and I realized I had to send screen views in Android too, to see campaign statistics in Google Analytics site.

So, what I'd like to know is,

1. Do I have to send screen views in Android too, to see statistics in Google Analytics site?
2. If I control "sampling frequency" < 100%, screen views and events are skipped by that ratio, I know. Then, Campaigns are also not transmitted and statistics in site are not precise? or Campaigns are transmitted unconditionally and statistics in site are precise?

Thanks in advance.